# LibGdx - How to set layers for the Sprites

Tags: java, libgdx, sprite, render, layer

Just for the start I'm new to the Java programming and especially to the LibGdx and I would like to ask community, because I have found some problem with Sprites, that I couldn't dealt with.

I create a several Sprites with Textures and I've managed to create a small function game, but when it comes to slide over an Sprite, it moves across him correctly, but not the way I want it to happend.

For example there are Sprites A and B. B is static on the render screen and the A is moving towards him. when the A is touching B and moving across B, I would like to be it, that A is at the top and the B is under the A, so it looks like the A is over the B. But in my case when this happens, the B is on top of A. So I'm asking if there is anyway how to set some privileg to be drawn at the top of other Sprite or, is there a better way to acomplish it.

Thanks for the support and help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on the order you write you code. 
In your renderer you should have something like :

```
    spriteBatch.begin();
    spriteB.draw(spriteBatch);
    spriteA.draw(spriteBatch);
    spriteBatch.end();
```

In this case, you draw spriteB first, and then you draw spriteA. That will make appear sprite A on top of spriteB.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, it works fine now, I tried this method, but I didn't realize, that I had one Sprite render first then I wanted to be.

Thanks again

Comment: No problem ! I see you are new on Stackoverflow : Don't forget to accept this answer as the solution by clicking the tick on the left of my message ;)